# QML vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, qml, theory

What are the differences and similarities between QML and Javascript?

I am doing research on it, as I will probably give of a small presentation about QML soon. I have already looked at it on wikipedia, but I was hoping to get some answers from people with experience.

Note: I know some QML, I don't know any Javascript.

Comment: javascript is one of if not the most widely used programming language. surely the internet has already said enough about it that you don't need SO to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 6):

QML is a declarative language describing a tree of objects (in the QtQuick case a tree of visual items). The documentation has a [fairly comprehensive documentation of the language](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlreference.html). QML is used in the Qt framework only.

Javascript is an imperative language. Javascript is a very popular language used in many different places, for example embeddded in HTML sites or as part of node.js servers.

QML can [actually include Javascript snippets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-topic.html), for example for bindings and signal handlers.

QML and Javascript serve very different purposes, so I don't see how to provide a list of similarities and differences.

Comment: Well, QML was definitely inspired from Javascript.

Comment: Being used for different purposes doesn't mean the languages can't be compared. Are type systems different? How much? Are algebraic data types supported? How the syntax is different? What're pros'n'cons of JS compared to QML? What're pros'n'cons of QML?

Answer (score 1):

Getting some downvotes there, my guess is that it is because you didn't research enough before coming here. And possibly because it doesn't sound like you are quite ready for a presentation on these languages.

But I'll see if I can at least point you in the right direction; QML is what is called a "markup language", not unlike XML, whereas Javascript is an "imperative language", like many others such as Python, C and Rust. More similar to Python, as it is also an "interpreted" language, whereas the others mentioned are "compiled" languages.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sad to see the question is closed, and OP is downvoted. It's the top result for `qml vs js` question, and is really interesting for me, as I'm badly know js, and don't know qml at all. Yet I'm interested in the differences because the both might be used for scripting in Window Manger kwin. Ofc there's a plenty of articles describing QML, and, perhaps, comparing it to JS as it is JS-derived — however this is the single result with the title clearly intending to compare the languages.